# Using lag() in dplyr doesnt work as expected

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
col1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
col2<-c(1,2,3,44,1,1,2,3,44,44,1,2,44,1,44)
df<-data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I am trying to group by col1 entries, and find, for each grouping of col1, values of col2 that are equal to 44 and followed immediately by a smaller entry (<44), and FLAG such entries in a new column.

However, this code doesnt seem to work:

```
df %>% group_by(col1)  %>% mutate(FLAG=(col2==44 & lead(col2,1)<44))

    col1  col2  FLAG
   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1      1     1 FALSE
2      1     2 FALSE
3      1     3 FALSE
4      1    44  TRUE
5      1     1 FALSE
6      2     1 FALSE
7      2     2 FALSE
8      2     3 FALSE
9      2    44 FALSE
10     2    44  TRUE
11     3     1 FALSE
12     3     2 FALSE
13     3    44  TRUE
14     3     1 FALSE
15     3    44    NA
```

Specifically, entry 10 should be FALSE, since it has no entry <44 in the same grouping directly following it.  Any suggestions on how to write code that works more generally to do what I want?

Comment: I get NA in row 10 when I run your code (which is the expected behavior).

Comment: I don't. Are you sure? I just double-checked

Comment: Not sure why my computer is giving different results.

Comment: I don't know why we're getting different results. I'm also wondering why you're getting NA in row 15 but not in row 10. What happens when you run your code in a clean session with just `dplyr` loaded?

Comment: I updated dplyr and it seems to work.  Weird.  :) Thanks!

Comment: Other packages have `lead` and `lag` functions that behave differently than `dplyr` versions. My guess is you had masked the `dplyr` versions with those from another package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way by using `if_else` function of `dplyr` package

```
df %>% group_by(col1)  %>% mutate(FLAG=if_else(col2==44 & lead(col2,1)<44,TRUE,FALSE,missing = FALSE))
# Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
# Groups: col1 [3]
# 
# col1  col2  FLAG
# <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1      1     1 FALSE
# 2      1     2 FALSE
# 3      1     3 FALSE
# 4      1    44  TRUE
# 5      1     1 FALSE
# 6      2     1 FALSE
# 7      2     2 FALSE
# 8      2     3 FALSE
# 9      2    44 FALSE
# 10     2    44 FALSE
# 11     3     1 FALSE
# 12     3     2 FALSE
# 13     3    44  TRUE
# 14     3     1 FALSE
# 15     3    44 FALSE
```

Comment: when I run this I still get entry 10 as TRUE.  Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the condition that `lead(col2)` may not be NA.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1)  %>% 
  mutate(FLAG = (col2 == 44 & lead(col2, 1) < 44 & !is.na(lead(col2, 1))))

Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: col1 [3]

    col1  col2  FLAG
   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1      1     1 FALSE
2      1     2 FALSE
3      1     3 FALSE
4      1    44  TRUE
5      1     1 FALSE
6      2     1 FALSE
7      2     2 FALSE
8      2     3 FALSE
9      2    44 FALSE
10     2    44 FALSE
11     3     1 FALSE
12     3     2 FALSE
13     3    44  TRUE
14     3     1 FALSE
15     3    44 FALSE
```

Comment: Not sure why both your solutions seem to work, but not on my computer....

Comment: @user85727 maybe try updating R/dplyr?

Comment: I think this may be the issue. Weird, it said I had the latest version installed....

Comment: How can I change this code to flag all leading 44s prior to an entry less than 44 so that                                                                                                  col2<-c(1,1,1,1,44,44,44,1,44,44,1,2,44,3,44)
 col1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
 df<-data.frame(col1,col2)                                       gives me TRUE for entries 5,6, and 7 as well?

Comment: @user85727 Sorry, I don't understand how col1 in rows 5 and 6 fulfills the conditions such that "all leading 44s prior to an entry less than 44"

Comment: Sorry, rows 6 and 7.  All consecutive 44s prior to a value less than 44, i.e., 44, 44, 44, 1 would make all 44s TRUE instead of just the value of 44 one row above the 1.